# How to avoid having to do sorting two times a javascript array with 2 conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, underscore.js

I have an orders array and I need to sort it based on the `delivery_time` attribute so that the earliest orders can be processed first. But we have an option to deliver order immediately as well. So irrespective of the delivery time the immediate `delivery_method` orders need to be at the beginning of the array.

Right now I am achieving this by using 2 sort functions, first one sorts the orders based on the `delivery_time` attribute and the second one sorts the array based on the `delivery_method_id` attribute (`delivery_method_id == 1` means its immediate delivery). How can I achieve the same result using only one `sort` function?

```
orders.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.delivery_time - b.delivery_time; //sort based on delivery_time
}).sort((a, b) => {
  return a.delivery_method_id === 1 ? -1: 0; //sort based on delivery_method_id 
});
```

I tried keeping both conditions in the first sort function itself but in that case, I get the Immediate delivery orders in each days beginning position rather than in the first position (I hope I am clearly explaining this situation)

How can I avoid using two functions to sort this orders array? I have underscore.js installed if it can be used its ok as well.

**Sample Data(orders)**

```
[{
  "id": 149677,
  "delivery_time": "2020-02-20 19:00:00",
  "delivery_method_id": 2
}, {
  "id": 149737,
  "delivery_time": "2020-02-20 21:00:00",
  "delivery_method_id": 2
}, {
  "id": 160919,
  "delivery_time": "2020-03-12 13:00:00",
  "delivery_method_id": 3
},
{
  "id": 160920,
  "delivery_time": "2020-03-12 13:00:00",  // according to delivery time, this should be at the bottom, but because the delivery_method_id == 1 , I need to push this to the top/beginning of array, this is why I had to use 2 sorts
  "delivery_method_id": 1
}]
```

Comment: Show sample data and expected order

Comment: How should multiple immediate delivery method entries be sorted? What are the other values for `delivery_method_id` for non-immediate deliveries?

Comment: I have updated the sample data, and the other `delivery_method_id` 's are 2 and 3,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This always orders objects with a `delivery_method_id` of 1 first, but if that is true of both objects the `delivery_time` is still used to sort between them. When neither object has a `delivery_method_id` of 1, only the `delivery_time` is used for sorting.

```js
console.log([
  {id: 1, delivery_method_id: 2, delivery_time: 1},
  {id: 2, delivery_method_id: 1, delivery_time: 2},
  {id: 3, delivery_method_id: 1, delivery_time: 2},
  {id: 4, delivery_method_id: 1, delivery_time: 1},
  {id: 5, delivery_method_id: 1, delivery_time: 2},
  {id: 6, delivery_method_id: 3, delivery_time: 7},
  {id: 7, delivery_method_id: 3, delivery_time: 8},
  {id: 8, delivery_method_id: 3, delivery_time: 6},
  {id: 9, delivery_method_id: 2, delivery_time: 6}
].sort((a, b)=>{
  return a.delivery_method_id === 1 ?
    (b.delivery_method_id === 1 ? a.delivery_time - b.delivery_time : -1) :
    (b.delivery_method_id === 1 ? 1 : a.delivery_time - b.delivery_time)
}))
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Since I don't need to sort the other orders based on the `delivery_method_id`. Little tricky ternary conditon, But this is it, Thank you

Answer (score 3):

So assuming you also want 2 and 3 to be after it, then we would just check to see if ids are equal, if they are we sort by date, if they are not, we sort by id.

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 149677,
    "delivery_time": "2020-02-20 19:00:00",
    "delivery_method_id": 2
  }, {
    "id": 149737,
    "delivery_time": "2020-02-20 21:00:00",
    "delivery_method_id": 2
  }, {
    "id": 160919,
    "delivery_time": "2020-03-12 13:00:00",
    "delivery_method_id": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 160920,
    "delivery_time": "2020-03-12 13:00:00",
    "delivery_method_id": 1
  }
]

var updated = data.sort((a,b) => {
  var sortProp = a.delivery_method_id === b.delivery_method_id ? 'delivery_time' : 'delivery_method_id'
  return a[sortProp] > b[sortProp] ? 1 : -1
})

console.log(updated)
```

Comment: Thank you, Your answer gave me somewhat right answer, but I don't need to sort based on the `delivery_method_id` at all. Thank you :)

Comment: And hence why you need to give details so one does not assume things. So it is a simple if check.....

Comment: Yes. I agree there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const orders = [{
  "id": 149677,
  "delivery_time": "2020-02-20 19:00:00",
  "delivery_method_id": 2
}, {
  "id": 149737,
  "delivery_time": "2020-02-20 21:00:00",
  "delivery_method_id": 2
}, {
  "id": 160919,
  "delivery_time": "2020-03-12 13:00:00",
  "delivery_method_id": 3
},
{
  "id": 160920,
  "delivery_time": "2020-03-12 13:00:00",  // according to delivery time, this should be at the bottom, but because the delivery_method_id == 1 , I need to push this to the top/beginning of array, this is why I had to use 2 sorts
  "delivery_method_id": 1
}] 

orders.sort((a,b) => {
  if((a.delivery_method_id === 1 && b.delivery_method_id === 1) || (a.delivery_method_id !== 1 && b.delivery_method_id !== 1)){
    return a.delivery_time - b.delivery_time
  }
  return a.delivery_method_id === 1 ? -1 : 1
})

console.log(orders)
```